# using Guzzle to get request in async mode

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

i have this below code as:

```
public function postGuzzleRequest()
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $url = "http://myexample.com/api/posts";
    $myBody['name'] = "Demo";
    $request = $client->post($url,  ['body'=>$myBody]);
    $response = $request->send();
    dd($response);
}
```

now i'm trying to use that in async mode

Comment: What exactly is your question? Be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taken directly from the doc:
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

```
$promise = $client->getAsync('http://httpbin.org/get');
$promise = $client->deleteAsync('http://httpbin.org/delete');
$promise = $client->headAsync('http://httpbin.org/get');
$promise = $client->optionsAsync('http://httpbin.org/get');
$promise = $client->patchAsync('http://httpbin.org/patch');
$promise = $client->postAsync('http://httpbin.org/post');
$promise = $client->putAsync('http://httpbin.org/put');
```